# preg_replace() pattern to remove brackets and content in php

Tags: php, design-patterns, preg-replace

I want to remove the brackets with its content using preg_replace(), but i am unable to use a lazy(non-greedy) in the pattern since the end bracket is the end character, the text in between the brackets is always a random character length and can contain numbers, underscores, and hyphens.

code-

```
$array = array(
   "Text i want to keep (txt to remove)",
   "Random txt (some more random txt)",
   "Keep this (remove)",
   "I like bananas  (txt)"
);

$pattern = "@pattern@";
foreach($array as $new_txt){
   $new_outputs .= preg_replace($pattern, '', $new_txt)."\n";
}
echo $new_outputs;
```

Wanted output-

```
Text i want to keep
Random txt
Keep this
I like bananas
```

I do not use regular expressions much and couldn't find anything to solve my problem.

Comment: What do you mean "unable to use a lazy in the pattern"?

Comment: It's what i call a non-greedy XD

Comment: So you know that non-greedy `*` exists, like in my answer. Why didn't you think you could use it?

Comment: I did try using it but it never worked the way's i tried like -> @((.*?))@ like i say i don't use regex much

Comment: You have to escape special characters if you want them to be treated literally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following regular expression should do it:

```
$pattern = '@\(.*?\)@';
```

`.*?` is a non-greedy match of anything.

Comment: doesn't the `?` mean 0 or 1 matches of the preceding character?

Comment: Not when it's after `*` or `+`, then it means non-greedy.

Answer (score 3):

```
$new_outputs .= preg_replace('@\([^\)]*\)$@','',$new_txt);
```

Comment: Is the part to remove always at the end? This regexp assumes it is.

Comment: That's what i took from the post. but if that's not intended, remove the `$`

Comment: All the answers work, I am pleased by asking In the right place and yes the brackets are always at the end of the strings, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you:

```
$pattern = "/\([^)]*\)+/";
foreach($array as $new_txt){
    $new_outputs .= preg_replace($pattern, '', $new_txt)."\n";
}
```

Comment: Why `\)+`? The question never mentioned what to do if there are multiple close parentheses.

Comment: @Barmar - Oh, sorry i did not noticed for that.